# Swift Compiler Error,Expression type 'Error' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift

```
typealias SwiftAMapCompletion = (CLLocation?,AMapLocationReGeocode?,Error) -> Void
var locationResult : SwiftAMapCompletion?
```

I want to give a nil as Error, but "Swift Compiler Error" is

> Expression type 'Error' is ambiguous without more context.(SwiftAMapCompletion can't change)

```
locationResult!(location, reGeocode, nil as! Error)
```

Comment: typealias SwiftAMapCompletion = (CLLocation?,AMapLocationReGeocode?,Error) -> Void

Comment: var locationResult : SwiftAMapCompletion?

Comment: locationResult!(location, reGeocode, nil as! Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force nil to be an Error, not even if you use `as!`.

Your options are:

1. Change the declaration to be `Error?`, because that would mean that you can pass nil.
2. Pass an Error.

For example:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case ok
}
locationResult!(location, reGeocode, MyError.ok)
```

In my opinion, your `SwiftAMapCompletion` interface does not make any sense, because normally a callback like this would be "here is the result, or here is the error" so all parameters should be declared as optional (with `?`).  I would get this interface changed if you can.